# Interaction between entity and tiles

Tags: architecture, tiles, design-patterns

In my game, I have a player, ennemies and tiles like Mario. And each entity has a different behavior when it touches a tile. For exemple, when my player walks on spike he dies. But a certain type of ennemy can walk on spike without dying.

Is there a good way to write this interaction between objets in OOP. I mean without cast, without breaking OCP principle and not having to write every behavior in every objects. Is there a design pattern for this purpose ?

Comment: I touched on an example like the spikes in an [earlier answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/127877/39518) using [the component pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html) to separate things that deal damage on collisions and things that can be damaged (or resist/ignore certain types of damage)